# What can I use as a globally-unique function identifier within a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to generate a unique identifier for any function within my program.

The code may contain multiple files, classes and functions of possibly identical names.

I believe that using the `inspect` module, I can add the following snippet inside any given function, in order to yield a globally-unique identifier of that function:

```
x = inspect.currentframe()

guid = x.f_code.co_name + ' ' + x.f_code.co_filename

if 'self' in x.f_locals:
    guid = x.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__ + '.' + guid
```

just to clarify, my ultimate goal is to scan the call-stack inside **a very specific function** in my program - one which may be called from various places within the code - and identify each function in that call-stack:

```
guids = {}

x = inspect.currentframe()

while x is not None:
    guid = x.f_code.co_name + ' ' + x.f_code.co_filename

    if 'self' in x.f_locals:
        guid = x.f_locals['self'].__class__.__name__ + '.' + guid

    guids[guid] = True

    x = x.f_back

return guids
```

Can I rely on the fact that `guid` is always generated in a unique manner?

Comment: No.  For example, it would be a pathological case, but I can do `def xxx():` three different times in my code, and call you from each one.

Comment: @TimRoberts: In the code where? They'd have to be in different scopes, which I am identifying by checking the class and the file (though I admit that I haven't account for static class functions). What other types of scopes should I be accounting for?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pathological example:

```
def xxx():
    print("I am number 1.")
    call_your_function()
xxx()

def xxx()
    print("I am number 2.")
    call_your_function()
xxx()

def xxx()
    print("I am number 3.")
    call_your_function()
xxx()
```

That's perfectly valid Python code, although stupid.  You would get three calls from three different functions where the file name and function name are the same.

I call it "pathological" because no reasonable programmer would do that, but it's certainly possible.